# accumulation point of a sequence

Tags: analysis

$$(c_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\ \ \text{is a sequence with } \ c_{n+2}=\frac{1+c_{n+1}}{c_{n}}\ \ \text{and} \ \ c_{0}=1,c_{1}=2$$

I want to show that $$\{1,2,3\}$$ are the accumulation points of the sequence, but i don't know how to show for example that there exist an infinite number of s_{n} s.t.:
$$\vert c_{n}-a \vert \le \epsilon ,\forall n\ge n_{\epsilon}, a\in \{1,2,3\}$$

Can anyone give me a hint how to solve this problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we try writing out the first few terms in the series, we get:
$$
1,2,3,2,1,1,2,...
$$
Which repeats indefinitely, since we see that we get back to consecutive $1,2$.
(i.e., we see that if $c_n =1, c_{n+1}=2$, then $c_{n+5}=1, c_{n+6}=2$, and also that $c_{n+2}=c_{n+7}=3$. Thus, the subsequences $\{c_{n+5k}\}_k$, $\{c_{n+1+5k}\}_k$, $\{c_{n+2+5k}\}_k$, are all constant with values $1,2,3$).

Comment: But how can i write it mathematically down?

Comment: I've expanded the answer a bit, is that what you meant?

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much!